# Referenced custom control for windows form groupbox displays incorrectly

Tags: c#, windows, forms

So the custom control form looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8FEr.png

However, whenever I reference this custom control, OAuthControl.cs, the groupbox of which the buttons and textboxes are organized under displays incorrectly. Here is a picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8FEr.png#1

I tried changing the margin and padding properties for that groupbox and only got it to partially display more of the bottom half.

What can I change to make each control that I reference in a new form to conform to the original control design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I can't comment under your question.
Probably is related to Anchor (I immagine that buttons ar anchored) or something you do in OAuthControl.cs
Could you post it?

Comment: Hi Bubi, here are the source files for that control.

http://www.filedropper.com/controls

Comment: You have to fix Anchor property of various controls on OAuthControl.
You can do what you need but I suggest you to
1. Anchor the Group to everything (actually is not Anchored).
2. Anchor the other controls to top and "in Width" (Anchor top, left and right)

Comment: Fiddling with the anchor property moves the content within the groupbox around but much of the content is still hidden. The groubox in the control is just smaller when referenced. In design form, the groubox is big enough to contain all the information. What could cause that?

Comment: Modifying the minimum size of the groupbox seems to have fixed this problem as it keeps it from shrinking. Lets see if there are any other workarounds.